# Unique sums greater than a number

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I'm trying to write a code that takes a list of numbers between 1 and 10 and finds sums that are greater or equal than 10 and then remove those numbers from the list. Here's the twist: first you need to check if there is any 10 in the list, the any couple of numbers that sum to 10, then any 3 numbers and so on until 5. Also, the lower  the numbers summed the better. So you need to get rid of most numbers when summing couples. So far I managed to do the couples:

```
n = input("How many numbers in the list? \n")
throw = []
for i in range(int(n)):
    throw.append(random.randint(1, 10))
throw.sort()
increments = 0
print(throw)
increments += throw.count(10)
throw = list(filter(lambda i: i != 10, throw))

high = len(throw)-1
low = 0
acceptable_couples = []
get_rid = []
while low < high:
    sums = throw[high] + throw[low]
    if sums >= 10:
        increments += 1
        get_rid.append(throw[high])
        get_rid.append(throw[low])
        acceptable_couples.append((throw[high], throw[low]))
        high -= 1
        low += 1
    else:
        low += 1
for i in get_rid:
    throw.remove(i)
```

I also did the pairs of 3 and was thinking to apply the same method for 4, and 5:

```
 while len(throw) >= 3:
    z = 0
    x = list(itertools.combinations(throw, 3))
    for couple in x:
        if sum(couple) >= 10:
            z += 1
            i = list(couple)
            increments += 1
            for j in couple:
                throw.remove(j)
            break
        else:
            continue
    if z == 0:
        break
```

I was hoping to find a less messy way to do it. This works, but for large number of numbers it seems a lot of useless computation.
Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure I really understand the question.  Do you have the original prompt somewhere?  It seems to me that if the sum of all the elements of the list is >= 10, then all elements should be removed.  No?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that case perhaps this would be a solution. In pseudo code:

1. Read list of numbers and sort from high to low
2. remove all numbers 10 from the list and add these as a solution
3. Loop until list is empty
4. take the largest number in the list (which is the first number as list is sorted) and remove it from the list
5. Check if by adding the smallest number we can get a sum greater or equal to 10 if not go to a bigger number until we complete the loop. Break loop if a solution is found, add to solutions and remove the element from the list that solved it.
6. if solved break and repeat the outer while loop with next biggest number in the list. If not solved then add the next biggest number to the sum and remove it from the list and check if we can find a solution adding smaller numbers running the for loop again

Code

```
import random

n = int(input("How many numbers in the list? \n"))
throw = [random.randint(1, 6) for _ in range(n)]
print(throw)

throw.sort(reverse=True)
print(throw)

list_of_solved_sets = []

# remove all numbers 10 from the list and add a solution
while throw and throw[0] == 10:
    list_of_solved_sets.append([throw[0]])
    del throw[0]

while throw:

    # take the largest number in the set (which is the first number 
    # as list is sorted) and remove it from the list
    solved_set = [throw[0]]
    _sum = throw[0]
    del throw[0]

    while throw:
        solved = False

        # Check if by adding the smallest number we can get
        # a sum greater or equal to 10 if not go to a bigger number
        # until we complete the loop. Break loop if a solution is found, add
        # to solutions and remove element from the list that solved it
        for j in range(len(throw) - 1, -1, -1):
            if _sum + throw[j] >= 10:
                solved_set.append(throw[j])
                del throw[j]

                list_of_solved_sets.append(solved_set)

                solved = True
                break

        # if solved break and repeat the outer while loop with next biggest number
        # in the list. If not solved then add the next biggest number to the sum and      
        # check if we can find a solution adding smaller numbers running the for 
        #loop again
        if solved:
            break

        else:
            _sum += throw[0]
            solved_set.append(throw[0])
            del throw[0]

print('List of solved sets:')
for i, solved_set in enumerate(list_of_solved_sets):
    print(f'   {i+1}: {solved_set}')
```

Result example:

```
How many numbers in the list?
10
[3, 2, 5, 1, 6, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1]
[6, 5, 4, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1]
List of solved sets:
   1: [6, 4]
   2: [5, 3, 2]
   3: [3, 3, 2, 1, 1]
```

Comment: Almost! But I can use that! I just need to change [0] with [-1] in the last else cause i want to prioritize small numbers first...ie with your code in a list like [6, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2] I would get the sum as [ 6, 3, 2] but i want it to be [6, 2, 2]. Thank you so much!

Comment: You are welcome. If my answer helped you to get the solution, please can you tick as answered. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand your question correctly. My interpretation is that you have a set of numbers between 1 and 10 and you need to find the longest sub sets of numbers from this set that sum up to 10 or greater and then remove these numbers from the original set until you can not find any more sets with more than one number.

If this is the correct interpretation than the following should work:

```
import random

n = int(input("How many numbers in the list? \n"))
throw = [random.randint(1, 10) for _ in range(n)]
print(throw)

throw.sort()
list_of_solved_sets = []
sets_found = True

while sets_found:
    _sum = 0
    solved_set = []
    solved_indexes = []
    for index, element in enumerate(throw):
        _sum += element
        solved_set.append(element)
        solved_indexes.append(index)
        if _sum >= 10:
            break

    if len(solved_set) <= 1:
        sets_found = False

    else:
        list_of_solved_sets.append(solved_set)

        for index in reversed(solved_indexes):
            del throw[index]

print('List of solved sets:')
for i, solved_set in enumerate(list_of_solved_sets):
    print(f'   {i+1}: {solved_set}')
```

Note you need to remove the indexes from the list `throw` in reversed order!

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't clear. I need to find the least amount of number that sums to 10. For example:
throw = [1, 2, 3, 5, 9, 10]
I would first take out the 10, than do 9+1 and take them out, then 2+3+5, and so on